# how to make notification in receiver

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have the following code to make a notification when the network state changes.
but when i change the network state the app stops working !
please help me with making notification.

I am sure the problem is in addMyNotification  function . but dont know how to fix it.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent broadcast) {
    addMyNotification("hi","hello",1,context);
}





private void addMyNotification(String title,String message,int id ,Context context ) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SendFood.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   manager.notify(id, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: can you try adding log in your addMynotification function and check whether it is being called? also what does ur adb say?

Comment: how can i do this ? i am new to android